# Predicted probabilities from probit

Tags: stata, probit

Assume following probit model:

$y_i$ = $\phi$($\beta_0$+$\beta_1x_1$+$\beta_2x_1^2$+$\beta_3d_1$+$\beta_4d_2$)
where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are dummies

or in Stata:

```
probit y_i x1 xsq d1 d2
```

Now I want to predict the probabilities $P(\hat{y_i} = 1)$ for each observation x. This seems very simple but I keep failing to program it in Stata.

I tried:

```
predict pr, xb
```

But this gives me values greater than 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are retrieving the linear index. Try `predict predicted_probabilities, pr`.

Comment: Previous question title "Plot predicted probabilities of probit against observations" had nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is on the face of it a Stata question, but there is a statistical confusion at its core. Here is wrong and right syntax for what you want exemplified.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. probit foreign mpg weight

Iteration 0:   log likelihood =  -45.03321
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -29.244141
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -27.041557
Iteration 3:   log likelihood =  -26.84658
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -26.844189
Iteration 5:   log likelihood = -26.844189

Probit regression                                 Number of obs   =         74
                                                  LR chi2(2)      =      36.38
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -26.844189                       Pseudo R2       =     0.4039

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |  -.1039503   .0515689    -2.02   0.044    -.2050235   -.0028772
      weight |  -.0023355   .0005661    -4.13   0.000     -.003445   -.0012261
       _cons |   8.275464   2.554142     3.24   0.001     3.269438    13.28149
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. predict pr
(option pr assumed; Pr(foreign))

. predict xb, xb

. su pr xb

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
          pr |        74     .294487    .3074146   9.52e-06   .9029781
          xb |        74   -.9904795    1.376307  -4.275976   1.298709
```

As the help explains (just read `help probit postestimation`), the default for `predict` after `probit` is to give predicted probabilities, and that is what you want. By insisting on `xb`, you got the linear predictor. You can get what you want by pushing your predictions through the cumulative standard normal (in Stata `normal()`) but just using the default gets you there directly. In essence you want a back-transformation to the probability scale, but that is so common a need that Stata (and presumably all good statistical software) provides it directly.